# How to resolve the 'No JSON data to operate on!' error when generating reports with Jasperreports Server 8.1.1 using POST method?

Tags: jasperserver

Error generating report using POST method in jasper-reports Server

Found an error when generating a test report after migration from Jasperreports Server 6.4. ce to Jasperreports Server 8.1.1

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No JSON data to operate on!

The error does not depend on the amount of data, the report is either generated or not.
Report - PostDemoReport.zip
3_error_json.json - I get the error: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No JSON data to operate on!
JSON is valid

3_success_json.json - Report generated successfully
This package differs from the first one by 4 sections - they have been removed.

On Jasperreports Server 6.4.2 CE version - the error is not reproduced
On versions of Jasperreports Server 7.5 - 8.2 community edition , - the error is reproduced

Files to reproduce the error are available at the link

https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/14636